# Conformal mapping of a curve

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, conformal-geometry

How can we define, what a conformal mapping of a curve is? Can we say that this is a map that preserves the oriented angle between any two points on the curve? Or is there an another (better, more accurate) definition?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is any 'good' definition. Is there a context?

Answer (score 0):

I believe by consulting "The Ambient Metric," by Charles Fefferman and C. Robin Graham (Annals of Mathematical Studies, Number 178, Princeton University Press, 2012), you will discover on page 1 that "Conformal geometry is the study of spaces where one knows how to measure infinitesimal angles but not lengths."  It goes on to discuss a conformal structure on manifolds.  Whether this is of any use to you, I do not know, however I wish you well in your studies.